# iPhone : Problem regarding Hidden TabBar Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to hide tabbarcontroller on one view.

But doing so it is displaying white space and not allowing to put any image or anything else on that place.

So what should I do ?

Comment: You could show the progress bar in some other view.

Comment: u want to hide tabbar on any event? or at startup time?

Comment: want to hide tabbar and I want to display any image on that place

Answer (score 0):

Put one imageView with your desired image on the view controller where you do not want to show tabBar and hide tabBarController before pushing that view on navigation stack using code like

```
[viewControllerInstanceWhichIsGoingToPushed hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
```

The method is something like this. Then Tab Bar will hide and your imageView with image will be displayed in place of TabBar.

Comment: I have tried to put image on the place of tabbar but it is showing only white space.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the viewController where you want to hide tabbar?

Answer (score 0):

*If you add a subview to a hidden view, the subview will also go hidden.*

In your case, you can have another view controller with just the activity indicator and display the view controller while the loading operation is done. And, after the loading is over, remove that view controller and show the tab bar controller. An example,

```
// while loading the content
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = loadingViewController;

// once the loading is over
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before as well and was not able to get anything to get into the blank space using the normal hierarchy. I got around this problem by adding another level of navigation.

**ex:**

right now you have at `UITabBarController` which contains your `UIViewControllers`.

**Instead:**

Have another `UIViewController` as the root and then add the tabbarcontroller onto it either as a modalviewcontroller or as a pushed viewcontroller (if you make your root a navigationcontroller). Then, your rootviewcontroller can freely put views under or over the tabbarcontroller's view, independent of whether the bar is present or not.